# $P$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n$ , then which are correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Suppose that $P$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n$ in one variable with real coefficients and $K$ is a real number. Then which of the following statements are necessarily correct ?
>
> 1. If $n$ is even and $K>0$ then there exists $x_0\in \mathbb R$ such that $P(x_0)=Ke^{x_0}$.
> 2. If $n$ is odd and $K<0$ , then there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(x_0)=Ke^{x_0}$.
> 3. For any natural number $n$, and $0<K<1$ then there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(x_0)=Ke^{x_0}$.
> 4. If $n$ is odd and $K \in \mathbb R$ , then there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(x_0)=Ke^{x_0}$.

For (3), consider, $P(x)=x^2+5$. Then , there does not exist $x_0\in \mathbb R$ such that $0<e^{-x_0}P(x_0)<1$. So it is FALSE.

But what about the others ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem):
1) Since $n$ is even, $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} P=\infty$. From that, we know that $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\frac{P(x)}{e^x}=\infty$. We also know that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(x)}{e^x}=0$. Therefore, there is a value $x_0$ verifying $\frac{P(x_0)}{e^{x_0}}=K$ (Since $0<K$).

2) Since $n$ is odd, $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} P=-\infty$. From that, we know that $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\frac{P(x)}{e^x}=-\infty$. We also know that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(x)}{e^x}=0$. Therefore, there is a value $x_0$ verifying $\frac{P(x_0)}{e^{x_0}}=K$ (Since $0>K$).

3) Your justification seems to be false, since $\lim\limits_{x_0\to\infty} e^{-x_0}P(x_0)=0^+$. Instead consider $K=\frac{1}{2}$, and $P(x)=x-1$.

4) Consider $K=1$, and $P(x)=x-1$.

Comment: You should at least mention the mean value theorem :)

Comment: Well, I think you mean the intermediate value theorem :)

Comment: Err, yes. This is funny.

Comment: @@GBQT) (1) and (2) are clear,...For , option (4) , from your example , $x-1=e^x$ has no real solution. How you can conclude it ? Similarly for (3) ?

Comment: @@GBQT Please response...

Comment: In order to prove that $x-1=e^x$ has no solution, we'll prove that $f(x)=x-1-e^x<0$. This is true for $x=0$. Then I notice that the derivative of $f(x)$ is $1-e^x$, which is negative over $\mathbb R+$ and positive over $\mathbb R-$. Therefore, for any $x \in \mathbb R$, $f(x) \leq f(0)<0$.